# Storing/retrieving DateTime

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, android-listview

I've an app that is retrieving a date that is stored as a string as a millisecs from 1970, eg  `1324657734883`.

I have a `ListView` that displays this date asis. I'd like to display the joda `DateTime` from this field in the database. My view displays the listview and populates it by using `startManagingCursor()` so i don't think there is any way of converting the `milisec` format to a `DateTime` before it is populated to the `listview`.

Is there a way around this or do i have to store a DateTime and if so what is the column type i need to declare to store this type of data?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();

    // setup UI
    setContentView(R.layout.viewtransactions);
    setTitle(getCarername() + " has completed " + nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.getNumberOfTransactions() + " visits today");
    //transactionCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewtransactionsfordaycount);
    viewTransactions = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewtransactions);

    //transactionCount.setText("You have completed 6 transactions today");

    // get data
    cursor = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromTransactions();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // setup adapter and show the data




    String[] from = { 
            LoginValidate.C_NAME, LoginValidate.C_TAG_SCAN_TIME,
            LoginValidate.C_TAG_SCAN_TIME};
    int[] to = { R.id.rowcarername, R.id.rowsignedinoutstatus, R.id.rowsenttoserverat };

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(nfcscannerapplication, R.layout.rowdataactual,
            cursor, from, to);
    viewTransactions.setAdapter(adapter);


}

}
```

.

[update1]
    public class ViewTransactions extends NfcBaseActivity{

```
private static final String TAG = ViewTransactions.class.getSimpleName();

NfcScannerApplication nfcscannerapplication;
Cursor cursor;
ListView viewTransactions;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
//TextView transactionCount; //now written to status bar

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();

    // setup UI
    setContentView(R.layout.viewtransactions);
    setTitle(getCarername() + " has completed " + nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.getNumberOfTransactions() + " visits today");
    //transactionCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewtransactionsfordaycount);
    viewTransactions = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewtransactions);

    //transactionCount.setText("You have completed 6 transactions today");

    // get data
    cursor = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromTransactions();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // setup adapter and show the data




    String[] from = { 
            LoginValidate.C_NAME, LoginValidate.C_TAG_SCAN_TIME,
            LoginValidate.C_TAG_SCAN_TIME};
    int[] to = { R.id.rowcarername, R.id.rowsignedinoutstatus, R.id.rowsenttoserverat };

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(nfcscannerapplication, R.layout.rowdataactual,
            cursor, from, to);
    viewTransactions.setAdapter(adapter);


}


class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
            int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public
    View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(v == null)
            return null;

        Cursor c = (Cursor)getItem(position);
        String val = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_TAG_SCAN_TIME));
        Date dt = new Date(Long.parseLong(val));
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
        String res = df.format(dt);

        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.rowsignedinoutstatus)).setText(res);
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.rowsenttoserverat)).setText(res);

        return v;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: There is a way around it, but you'll need to use your own adapter for this.

Comment: @aleks G hi, ok is that using something like a custom adapter? Would you like to give an answer and i'll accept it?

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adaptor-for-list-view

Comment: @turtleboy  Have a look at the answer.  I haven't tested it, so you may need to tweak it a bit, but you should get the idea.

Comment: @AleksG hi, yep i kinda worked it out, i've updated post with ammended code but my listview is now empty. Have you any ideas why. have i implemented how you suggested?

Comment: @turtleboy Have you tried stepping with the debugger through the `getView` method?  To make sure that it's called in the right place and processes the right values?

Comment: @AleksG erm no, i haven't used debugger before, i usually just use logging statments to logcat. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom adapter that extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`:

```
class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    @Override
    View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView();
        if(v == null)
            return null;

        Cursor c = (Cursor)getItem(position);
        String val = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_TAG_SCAN_TIME));
        Date dt = new Date(Long.parseLong(val));
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
        String res = df.format(val);

        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.rowsignedinoutstatus)).setText(res);
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.rowsenttoserverat)).setText(res);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Then use it in place of the default one:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(nfcscannerapplication, R.layout.rowdataactual, cursor, from, to);
```

Comment: @turtleboy Oh, sorry, of course not; it should be returning the view.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: i forgot to set the new custom adapter to the listview. the listview was still been passed the old adapter. it work fine thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateFormat` from [android.Text.DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html)

```
public static CharSequence getTimeStamp(long milliseconds) {
    Date d = new Date(milliseconds);
    return DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss aa", d);
}
```

But you will have to Use `ArrayAdapter<String>` for your `ListView`.

This will be easy if you use `LoaderManager`, instead of managing cursors from your Activity.